# fb-comments loader image does not disappear

Tags: facebook, image, loader

I have this simple html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
```

fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

The comments list shows incomplete, and the loader images never stops nor disappear. What can be going on

Thanks

Comment: do you get any javascript errors?

Comment: I have the same issue, hope someone knows a fix for this.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that adding OpenGraph tags to the page fixes the issue. It seems that the tags are used by Facebook to link back to the Comments on the page. I've also seen the issue appear in local environments, but resolve themselves when hosted.